# From address going into junk mail folder in hotmail

Tags: email, spam-prevention, hotmail

I have a certain email address that hotmail is sending all emails from to the junk folder. If I send the same email, from the same server, with the same content, but from a different email address it goes to the inbox.

Any ideas? The address is donotreply@ and I use this on other sites of mine and don't have any problems with the junk folder.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never find a confirmed answer for this question for a number of reasons.

1. Microsoft are a law unto themselves.
2. There is no way for you to confirm why. The actual reason for filtering is never released and therefore testing is pretty much useless. Microsoft just give a score and no individual reasons (like spamassassin)

However, it is likely that someone has previously flagged this email address as spam, probably not releasing that they actually signed up for it (and I hope they did). If the content is identical and the only thing that changes is the address, I can think of no other reason.

If it was a content issue, then in theory all emails from any address would get flagged.

If it was an IP reputation, same as above.

This leaves sender address.

Comment: yea, it's to bad Microsoft isn't more transparent about things like this. We have done everything we can get in their good books.

Comment: @david Have you signed up for their SNDS service and JMR? They both help to understand what they 'tnink' of you. Saying that, we have had problems and according to their own systems, everything is green!

Comment: yep, a member of that as well and we regularly prune if something doesn't get picked up by our automatic pruner.